# Python3 - installing Scapy in OS

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, scapy

I installed the networking module **Scapy**.
When I import scapy (`import scapy`) everything works fine. When I import all from scapy (`from scapy.all import *`), it brings up this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/***/Downloads/test.py", line 5, in <module>
from scapy.all import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 16, in <module>
from .arch import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
from .bsd import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/arch/bsd.py", line 12, in <module>
from .unix import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 22, in <module>
from .pcapdnet import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 22, in <module>
from .cdnet import *
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scapy/arch/cdnet.py", line 17, in <module>
raise OSError("Cannot find libdnet.so")
OSError: Cannot find libdnet.so
```

I found out on another post that we might have to download additionnal modules in order to make scapy fully work. What should be done exactly?
I tried using (port ** install) which didn't work because port is not supported anymore? If you have any idea how to make it work in python3, I will be active. Here is more additionnal informations:

```
python 3.4.3
mac os 10.10.4
scapy-python3==0.14
```

EDIT: Another interesting thing is :

On all OS except Linux libpcap should be installed for sending and receiving packets (not python modules - just C libraries). libdnet is recommended for sending packets, without libdnet packets will be sent by libpcap, which is limited. Also, netifaces module can be used for alternative and possibly cleaner way to determine local addresses.
Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scapy-python3/0.11

Dnet seems to only work with version 2.7 : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnet/1.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Up-to-date edit: this issue has been fixed on recent versions of scapy, simply update your scapy version using `pip install scapy>=2.4.0`**

You have to install libdnet. Not the python library (which does not work on python3 as you mentioned), but the library itself. There has to be library file libdnet.so somewhere in your system where python searches for libraries. Downloading the libdnet source and compiling should make it work:

```
wget http://libdnet.googlecode.com/files/libdnet-1.12.tgz
tar xfz libdnet-1.12.tgz
cd libdnet-1.12
./configure
make
```

Also, there is a possibility to use libpcap for sending packets and not to use libdnet, but I recommend trying to make libdnet work first.

Comment: I believe I tried this option but must not have put too much effort in it. I am using mac os 10.10.4, therefore how should I install it? (I believed I had trouble with these steps) Thank you a lot for your answer =)

Comment: If you have issues with installation, please, post details of the trouble. Or add an issue on http://github.com/phaethon/scapy

Comment: Everything installed perfectly (I believe). The only "problem" is that it gives me 2 warnings (are they important?) WARNING: Could not load module netifaces: No module named 'netifaces'
WARNING: Please, report issues to https://github.com/phaethon/scapy

Comment: netifaces is optional. It is alternative way to determine local IP addresses. If determining local packets work (you can check by looking at conf.route) you can ignore the warning. Or you can install it with `pip3 install netifaces`

Answer (score 3):

**You can now install this easily** with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) by using the command:

```
brew install libdnet
```

after you've installed Homebrew.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/secdev/scapy

cd scapy

./run_scapy
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.